# I am expecting actual output 8 but getting 2 as output

Tags: python-3.x

See my code below. I am expecting output `8` but I am getting `2`. What went wrong?

Pycharm IDE.

```
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):
    result = 1
    for index in range(pow_num):
        result = result * base_num
        return result


print(raise_to_power(2,3))
```

I am expecting actual output `8` BUT GETTING OUTPUT `2`.

Answer (score 2):

You're `return`ing the `result` after the first iteration every time (where `result` is always the `base_num`), you should move your `return` outside of the `for` loop:

```
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):
    result = 1
    for index in range(pow_num):
        result = result * base_num
    return result

print(raise_to_power(2,3))
```

Output:

```
8
```